# What to do when someone has 0% accept rate?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Should I just NOT ANSWER people with 0% accept rate (and of course tell them why)? Or should I just give them a link to the FAQ and tell them that accepting gives not only the person who answers them reputation points but them too? I don't really see it fair to those people that work hard to make a good answer and it really is a misuse of the site.

**Bottom line:** what to do when someone has a 0% accept rate?

Comment: You're not just writing an answer for the answerer. You're writing your answer for the internet at large.

Comment: Good point, thank you : )

Comment: Fun fact, comments that contain the words "accept rate" can be deleted by any user instantly! Obviously pointing out their accept rate will not be constructive. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125533

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not ask our big brothers?

- [Is it appropriate to comment on people's accept rate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate)
- [Why are consistent 0% accept rate users not punished?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34922/why-are-consistent-0-accept-rate-users-not-punished)
- [How to tell new users with 0% accept rate to improve it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45508/how-to-tell-new-users-with-0-accept-rate-to-improve-it)
- Or really, anything under https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accept-rate

In any case, my personal opinion is to add a short, *polite* comment urging the users to review past answers and accept them, e.g.

> Looks like you've already asked a bunch of questions but never [accepted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) any of the answers. I think you're more likely to get better answers this time if you take the time to review the answers to your old questions and [accept](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) the ones which have been most helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer : )

Comment: I think we may also need to go knocking on the doors upstairs because while accepted answers are mentioned in the FAQ, they don't appear until some of the sections are expanded.  I think we would have fewer problems if that information was presented more prominently.